# What is a: or n1: in this xslt stylesheet do?

Tags: xml, xslt

Sorry I am a complete noob to xslt and probably gonna stay that way but I am trying to figure out what `a:` and `n1:` do in the following:

```
<xsl:value-of select="/n1:node/n1:anothernode"/>
```

or

```
<xsl:value-of select="a:anode/a:anothernode"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are they not namespace definitions?

Comment: @Aaron: Almost... they're namespace prefixes. Namespace definitions look like `xmlns:n1="foo"`.

Comment: @LarshH Right...poor use of verbiage on my part...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In `a:anode` `a` is a namespace prefix and `anode` is a local name, both together form a qualified element name. Look in your stylesheet for an `xmlns:a="http://example.com/"` namespace declaration. The path `a:anode` selects any elements with local name `anode` in the namespace the prefix `a` is bound to in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

They're namespaces. Look at the namespaces declared in the stylesheet to find out what they actually are.